# Error Import Excel Date PHP

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have a problem trying to upload an excel to my database through PHP.

The format I have in the excel is dd/mm/yyyy and my sql needs yyyy/mm/dd

```
$_DATOS_EXCEL[$i]['ship_day']= $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()-  >getCell($headings['Ship Date'].$i)->getFormattedValue();
```

I tried
getFormattedValue('YYYY/MM/DD');

but doesnt work

I really appreciate if you can help me out with this.

Answer (score 0):

If your cell value really is an Excel serialized date/time value, and you know which cells contain these dates, then you can convert it directly to a PHP DateTime object

```
$dto = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHPObject(
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
        ->getCell($headings['Ship Date'].$i)
        ->getValue()
);
$_DATOS_EXCEL[$i]['ship_day'] = $dto->format('Y/m/d');
```

or to a Unix Timestamp

```
$unixTimestamp = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP(
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
        ->getCell($headings['Ship Date'].$i)
        ->getValue()
);
$_DATOS_EXCEL[$i]['ship_day'] = date('Y/m/d', $unixTimestamp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add three line after

```
"$_DATOS_EXCEL[$i]['ship_day']= $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()-  >getCell($headings['Ship Date'].$i)->getFormattedValue();"
```

this line......

```
$rearrange=$_DATOS_EXCEL[$i]['ship_day'];
$explode = explode("/",$rearrange);
$_DATOS_EXCEL[$i]['ship_day']= $explode[2]."/".$explode[1]."/".$explode[0];
```